# Setup external Bluetooth usb dongle

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, bluetooth

I want to use an external Bluetooth 5.1 USB adapter on Pi4. The chip on the adapter is Realtek RTL8671b. I googled how to get an external BT work and most of the tutorials suggest disabling the onboard BT.

I disabled the onboard BT by editing the config file. The external adapter gets detected properly with lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:a725 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth 5.1 Radio
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

However, when I check the status I get the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service bluetooth status
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
  Loaded: loaded  (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead)
  Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

After starting the BT service

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

I get

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-06-12 09:27:47 BST; 38min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 22365 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
        CPU: 67ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─22365 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

so I suppose the BT service is running properly now. However when I try to list or show the BT devices I get

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
```

I am a beginner with Raspberry pi's and know how to proceed and make this adapter work. Could someone please help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Reading `/boot/overlays/README` it seems to suggest that `disable-bt` does disable services relating to Bluetooth. Have you tried to use `bluetoothctl` to power off the on-board controller instead? The `bluetoothctl` commands you would need are `list`, `select`, and `power off`. If that worked you could create a [systemd service](https://blog.usedbytes.com/2019/11/run-at-startup-without-rc.local/) to do that at startup.

Comment: I have re-enabled the BT service (see my updated post). The main problem is bluetoothctl not seeing the external adapter when I use the "list" command. The adpater is detected when I use "lsusb". I haven't used the bluetoothctl to poweroff the onboard BT. Just disabled it using the config.txt file.

Comment: Also in the updated post, when I use show command it says no default controller available. So somehow bluetoothctl isn't detecting the external adapter

Comment: No controller is turning up in `bluetoothctl`. Have you tried *not* disabling bluetooth in the config.txt to see if both controllers turn up?

Comment: After enabling the onboard BT, it shows up as the only controller, "Controller DC:A6:32:EE:BD:75 raspberrypi [default]" . No sign of external adapter. lsusb still shows that the adapter is present

Comment: Seems like it might be a driver issue with the Realtek RTL8671b. https://linuxreviews.org/Realtek_RTL8761B

Comment: I just installed the driver files as mentioned in your link but bluetoothctl still refuses to see the adapter. Before installing the driver I checked the dmesg for bluetooth and it showed 8761b firmware not found but now I don't get any error so I believe the driver is properly installed. Some issue still persists but what that could be?